# Cannot run program on eclipse workplace

Tags: java, eclipse

I am very new to java and eclipse and when I click run for the code below nothing happens. The green loading bar pops up but nothing happens. I have tried to run other codes and they are perfectly fine.

```
import java.util.*;

public class CMIS242WK3BrunsonT {

public static void main(String[] args) {;
    
    // parent class Aircraft
    class Aircraft
    {
        // attributes
        int numberOfEngines;
        float length;
        float height;

        // constructor
        Aircraft(int numberOfEngines,float length,float height)
        {
            this.numberOfEngines=numberOfEngines;
            this.length=length;
            this.height=height;
        }
        public void fly()
        {
            System.out.println("All Aircrafts Fly");
        } 
    }

    // child class Helicopter
    class Helicopter extends Aircraft
    {
        // attributes
        float mainRotorBladeSize;
        float tailRotorBladeSize;

        // constructor
        Helicopter(int numberOfEngines,float length,float height,float mainRotorBladeSize,float tailRotorBladeSize)
        {
            super(numberOfEngines,length,height);
            this.mainRotorBladeSize=mainRotorBladeSize;
            this.tailRotorBladeSize=tailRotorBladeSize;
        }

        public void hovering(){
              System.out.println("Helicopter hovers");
        }
    }

    // child class Plane
    class Plane extends Aircraft
    {
        // attributes
        float wingSpan;

        // constructor
        Plane(int numberOfEngines,float length,float height,float wingSpan)
        {
            super(numberOfEngines,length,height);
            this.wingSpan=wingSpan;
        }
        public void gliding(){
              System.out.println("Plane Glides");
        }
    }
    class test {

        public void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            
            // creating instance of child classes 

            Helicopter helicopter=new Helicopter(2, 50, 30, 50, 40);
            helicopter.fly();
            helicopter.hovering();

            Plane plane=new Plane(4, 100, 50, 80);
            plane.fly();
            plane.gliding();

            sc.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

It would be great to receive some feedback on how to solve this problem. If more detail is needed I will try to answer your questions to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Your main method is empty.

Comment: Actually, it isn't strictly empty.  It has an empty statement (a `;`) and some inner class declarations.  But there is nothing that is actually executable.  So, unsurprisingly, it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recap the structure of your code:

- outer class

  - static main

    - local class#1
    - local class#2
    - local class#3
    - local class 'test'

      - method main (not static)

        - testing code

So basically you code does nothing, because the method `test.main()` is never called.
The local class 'test' is redudandent anyway, just move the code from it's method main to the static main of the outer class to get this structure:

- outer class

  - static main

    - local class#1
    - local class#2
    - local class#3
    - testing code

More elaborately change from

```java
    // code nested in CMIS242WK3BrunsonT.main
    class test {

        public void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            
            // creating instance of child classes 

            Helicopter helicopter=new Helicopter(2, 50, 30, 50, 40);
            helicopter.fly();
            helicopter.hovering();

            Plane plane=new Plane(4, 100, 50, 80);
            plane.fly();
            plane.gliding();

            sc.close();
        }
    }
```

to just

```java
        // code nested in CMIS242WK3BrunsonT.main

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        // creating instance of child classes

        Helicopter helicopter = new Helicopter(2, 50, 30, 50, 40);
        helicopter.fly();
        helicopter.hovering();

        Plane plane = new Plane(4, 100, 50, 80);
        plane.fly();
        plane.gliding();

        sc.close();
```

or alternatively to

```java
        class test {

            public void main(String[] args) {
                // same code as above
            }
        }
        new test().main(args);
```

The created instance of Scanner is redundant too, you can just remove `Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);` and `sc.close();` when you don't read from the input.

Apart from that when learning Java I would recommend to put each class into a separate .java file. That way you learn the aspects of visibility better. Local classes are rarely used in practice anyway.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean sorry

Comment: @Trevon22 I updated the answer. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: @Trevon22 PS: Since the question has been closed: It is probably better to ask beginner questions like this on a Java forum.

Comment: @Trevon22: The official Java tutorials are a very good starting point for learning Java as well: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/. This is very well reviewed. IMHO this is better than tutorialspoint or alike, because those often contain hidden errors.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help